# Misunderstanding with pointer and memory pool assignment

Tags: c, pointers

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the correct implementation for the code below. I am trying to implement a very basic memory pool, and have users be able to "create" objects from the pool.

One goal/objective of doing the union with 'buf' is to be able to easily searilize or read raw Msg from a byte stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// This is the object that everyone will create/use
struct Msg {
  union {
    // Unique msg id for users to do something based on id
    uint16_t msg_type;
    // Data right now is a fixed length of 8 bytes but if I wanted to 
    // change this requirement I could easily since we are allocating 
    // from a memory pool
    uint8_t* data;
  };
  // This is the pointer to the next spot in the memory pool.
  uint8_t* buf;
};

int main() {
  uint8_t memory_pool[100];
  // Somewhere in user code
  struct Msg* msg_ptr;
  // This doesnt work! Throws a seg fault.
  msg_ptr->buf = &memory_pool[0];
  // I thought by setting where buf points to I could something like
  msg_ptr->msg_id = 1234;
  msg_ptr->data[0] = 100;
  // And so on
  // The real implementation would have the user call something like below, where
  // my_memory_pool_get would assign 'buf' to the next available spot in the memory_pool
  my_memory_pool_get(msg_ptr)
  
  // Now if I make Msg.msg_id a pointer to a 16 bit int
  // uint16_t* msg_id
  // The above code works just have to do something like:
  struct Msg msg;
  msg.buf = &memory_pool[0];
  *msg.msg_id = 1234;
  if (*msg.msg_id == 1234) { }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler will almost certainly warn you about the uninitialized use of `msg_ptr` if you turn on warnings (gcc needs optimizations on as well).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory for msg_ptr so when you access `msg_ptr->buf` of course it will crash as msg_ptr is a pointer to some an object in memory that has not been allocated yet.

```
struct Msg* msg_ptr; 
// This doesnt work! Throws a seg fault.
msg_ptr->buf = &memory_pool[0];
```

The following does not crash because msg is not a pointer.  The msg is allocated on the stack.

```
// Now if I make Msg.msg_id a pointer to a 16 bit int
// uint16_t* msg_id
// The above code works just have to do something like:
struct Msg msg;
msg.buf = &memory_pool[0];
*msg.msg_id = 1234;
if (*msg.msg_id == 1234) { }
```

You probably want a function `my_memory_pool_get(msg_ptr)` to be written like:

```
Msg* my_memory_pool_get(){
    int offset = 0;

    // Calculate the position/offset and make sure there is room!
    int room = ... // figure out how to determine is there is room in the buffer.
    if (!room)
        return NULL;

    return &memory_pool[offset];
}
```

Comment: I am confused whats different from your Msg* my_memory_pool_get() returning a pointer to an index in array vs my implementation just doing it all in main?

Comment: my_memory_pool_get is a function that you haven't provided an implementation for.  I'm just suggesting how you might implement that.

Comment: Looking at your code again, there is nothing in Msg that tells you how long the data is.  So you won't know where one message starts and another one ends.  I think you need to think about it some more and update your question as to what you're actually wanting.